# right align text in menubar

Tags: html, css, email

I am coding a menubar for an e-mail - therefore the messy tables. I need the two menuoptions "Point" and "My profile" to be aligned in the right side of the table:

```html
<table class="organicweb1" style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px" align="center" valign="top">
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid red;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" width="35" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" width="590" valign="middle">
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="590">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:7px 0px 7px 0px" align="center" valign="middle">
                        <table style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:120%;color:#512DA8" align="center" valign="top">
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Book</a>
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Gift</a>
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Voucher</a>
                                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank"></a>
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none; background-color: red; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right;" target="_blank"><b>Point:</b></a>
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none; background-color: red; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right;" target="_blank"><b>My profile</b></a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td align="left" width="35" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hfsd62eg/)

I have tried to set a `text-align:right;` on the `a` tag, the `td` tag, but I cannot get the two options to align right.

I can align them right if I set the text-align on the table. But then all the text are aligned right.

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: First thing you are doing wrong, is you are not showing the relevant code directly inside the question.

Comment: The `a` element is only as wide as its content demands. Trying to align the text to either side of that is of course impossible - there is no space on either side of the text.

Comment: Ah yes of coursel. I can set each menu option in a td then

Comment: Maybe can try to use `float`. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LorekB/ydpbbayk/2/) out

Answer (score 1):

**I think this will work for you -**

I have put the inner table `width` to `100%` and split you `<a>` tag to two `<td>` and gave them `float`.

```html
<table class="organicweb1" style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px" align="center" valign="top">
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid red;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" width="35" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" width="590" valign="middle">
                <table style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="590">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:7px 0px 7px 0px" align="center" valign="middle">
                        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" width: "100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:120%;color:#512DA8;float:left" align="center" valign="top">
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Book</a>
                              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Gift</a>
                              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">Voucher</a>
                              <span>&nbsp;</span>
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none" target="_blank"></a>
                              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

                            </td>
                            <td style="float:right">
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none; background-color: red; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right;" target="_blank"><b>Point:</b></a>
                              <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                              <a href="http://example.com" style="color:#004b60;text-decoration:none; background-color: red; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-align: right;" target="_blank"><b>My profile</b></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width="35" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this is helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet:

```
<a href="http://example.com" 
style=
"color:#004b60;
text-decoration:none;
background-color: red;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
margin-left:250px;" 
target="_blank"><b>Point:</b>
</a>
```

use margin-left:250px;    instead of text-align: right;

check the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hfsd62eg/1/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I use a margin I will get problems on mobile devices.